# Different font size for same text (one part of the text with font size "X" and other with font size "Y")

Tags: html, css, fonts

Please refer the image attached,

[image]

Here you can see "8.5", in a circle, is actually the rating of the video shown.

Question : How can I show 8.5 as shown here, **8 with larger font size and 5 with smaller one** ?

I am looking for a font family / any simple solution, rather than processing the text and giving different font sizes for both of them.

Thanks in advance.

**edit** : what have you tried ? Actually nothing. But I have a idea of splitting the string and giving different font sizes for each string (I guess this is not the proper way of doing it).

may be something like this : `<span class="bigNum">8</span><span class="smallNum">.5</span>`

Comment: I have an answer, but your question is quite broad, shows no research, and is generally unproductive. I recommend showing some work and asking a more pointed question with some code example, or remove the question altogether.

Comment: Just inspect that element and see what is inside. But i think it's `<span class="bigNum">8</span><span class="smallNum">.5</span>`

Comment: By processing the text you mean taking "8.5", splitting by "." and then inserting "8" into different <span> (for instance) than "5". This wouldn't be so bad, would it?

Comment: @Justinas : Is that a proper way to do this ?

Comment: @trainoasis : Yes exactly.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra you can do that, why not?

Comment: @trainoasis : I know it will work, but is it a good practice?

Comment: I don't se a much better solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to give any film a 10 rating, you can use pseudo-element first letter

```
div::first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tGGmg/)

Answer (score 1):

The  solution mentioned by Justinas is just what you have to do!
Wrap your Text in two spans:

```
<span style="font-size:10px;">8</span><span style="font-size:8px;">.5</span>
```

Comment: what do you have in mind? you could work with just one span which scales down the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Check by adding this

**HTML**

```
<span class="big">8</span><span class="small">.5</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.big
{
  font-size:36px;
}
.small
{
  font-size:20px;
}
```